# How to make work Chrome extension's uncaught exceptions handler (which doesn't work because of CORS protection)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cors

I set uncaught exceptions handler `window.error = function(message, ...) {...}` handler inside one of content script JS file of a Chrome extension. Purpose is to catch all such errors inside the extension (content script Javascript files of it) and report them to developers. But instead of real error message and stack trace I always get message "Script error" (occurred at line 1). How can I get real error and stack trace?

Here is what I found to that moment. It is because of CORS protection which by default sanitize the contents of the error if the script in which the error occurred isn't from the same origin as the document that loaded the script. Chrome since version 30 has support of bypassing this protection (["if the script is served with appropriate 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers that
grant the loading document access to the script's contents"](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159566#c23)). But how can I apply that bypass if content scripts are not served by HTTP but specified in an extension's manifest? For the same reason I can't use crossorigin attribute of `<script>`.

Also I suspected it can be done through content security police (`content_security_policy` manifest field) but I couldn't yet.

I realize that answer can be found by reading chromium sources but I hope somebody will tell me it and I will not need read them.

Comment: Do you want to see errors that are coming from another extension script or from an on-page script? If an extension script, is it another content script alongside your `window.error` content script?

Comment: @arspillers Purpose is to catch all such errors inside the extension (content script Javascript files of it)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that other than waiting for http://crbug.com/225513 to be fixed